# How to use a list of objects in razor with click handlers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I am using Razor to render a list of items, and I have a **delete** button for each item. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
//razor
@for (var item in Model.myList) {
  <div>@item.Name <button onclick='deleteItem(@item.Id)' class='delete-button' value='Delete' /></div>
}

//javascript
<script>
  function deleteItem(id) {
    //ajax stuff to delete here...
    alert('Item has been deleted');
  }
</script>
```

The code works great. But in a code review I was recently told I should

1. Use a de-coupled click handler
2. Use the `data` attribute

like this:

```
//razor
@for (var item in Model.myList) {
  <div>@item.Name <button data-id='@item.Id' class='delete-button' value='Delete' /></div>
}

//javascript
<script>
  $( "div button.delete-button" ).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //do ajax stuff here to delete
    alert('Item has been deleted');
  });
</script>
```

This also works, and does essentially the same thing. But I wanted to know **if there is any tangible benefit (performance, testing, code-readability, etc) to using a de-coupled click handler**? Or is it more of a personal preference? We have around 100 items in the list on average.

Comment: The 2nd example is recommended as it separates behavior from markup - suggest you read about [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Second one is better than first due to split between client-side event handlers and markups. The benefit of unobtrusive mode has more weight in readability and scalability, also includes behavior testing.